# Java classes List not updating from List in another class

Tags: java

I do believe that answer should already be somewhere on so, but after some search I still cant figure out my problem..

```
public class cl1{   
private List<Map> world_map = new ArrayList<Map>();

public List<Map> returnmap(){
return world_map;
}

public void addtomap(float x, float y, int type){
Map tile = new Map();
tile.x = x;
tile.y = y;
tile.type = type;
world_map.add(tile);
}
}
```

Activity class:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View vw) {

            List<Map> map = new ArrayList<Map>();
            map = robot.returnmap();

            for(int i=0;i<map.size();i++){
                txt.setText(String.valueOf(i));
            }

            cl1.addtomap(x, y, 1);
            x++;
            y++;


        }
```

This works fine: I can add to cl1.world_map with my method from activity class, and I can also get values from world_map from my activity class.

I have another class:

```
protected List<Map> strap = new ArrayList<Map>();

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    returnmap();
    canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(strap.size()), 100, 120, paint1);
}

private void returnmap(){
    strap = robot.returnmap();
}
```

Here I'm always getting value of 0, like the "List strap" would never update?

Comment: where are you updating your Map in this class. and what's robot.returnmap() does?

Comment: sorry, my hands are quicker than my mind... robot.returnmap() is calling function returnmap() in the cl1 class (cl1 = robot). In the last class I'm just trying to get the values from the Map, I update the Map only in the Activity class (cl1.addtomap(x,y,1)).

Comment: is it the same object of cl1 class is shared between both parts? If yes, it will. If no, it will not. Understand the basics of Object. :)

Comment: Where is `robot` defined? And what is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your 'robot' variable is probably getting re-instantiated or is not even the same instance in your two classes, if that is not the case, keep in mind that in android there are many events under which you could get your fragments or activities re-instantiated and you should always save the state you intend to keep yourself